# Сравнение разности двух вещественных чисел с третьим вещественным числом

Tags: c++, c, double

У меня есть вещественные числа `a`, `b` и `с`.
Нужно чтобы выполнялось выражение `c == (b - a)`, проблема возникает именно с "равно".
Думал использовать `fabs((b - a) - c) < DBL_EPSILON`, но не выходит.

Comment: Что не выходит?

Comment: Вы неправильно используете `DBL_EPSILON`.

Comment: ИСПРАВЛЕНО. При сравнении, например, 0.2 == (1.4 - 1.2) результат - false, если fabs((1.4 - 1.2) - 0.2) < DBL_EPSILON

Comment: Почему Вы решили, здесь надо использовать `DBL_EPSILON`? - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Shared/MS/Internal/DoubleUtil.cs,731dadb9ea68ce09,references

Comment: Посмотрите функцию `AreClose` по ссылке.

Comment: Потому, что если числа равны, то поскольку для double оператор "==" использовать не корректно, то следует вместо if (a == b) использовать fabs(a - b) < DBL_EPSILON, если a и b - double.

Comment: Я хочу это сделать методами стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: "то следует вместо ..." - это цитата откуда-то или Ваши мысли? Это неправильно. Функцию `AreClose` надо посмотреть, чтобы понять смысл `DBL_EPSILON` и как им пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // ..
    AreClose(b - a, c);
   // ...
    static bool AreClose(double value1, double value2)
    {
        //in case they are Infinities (then epsilon check does not work)
        if (value1 == value2) return true;
        // This computes (|value1-value2| / (|value1| + |value2| + 10.0)) < DBL_EPSILON
        double eps = (fabs(value1) + fabs(value2) + 10.0) * DBL_EPSILON;
        double delta = value1 - value2;
        return(-eps < delta) && (eps > delta);
    }
```